# Adding two numbers in lightswitch 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, addition, lightswitch-2013

I used this code for adding two numbers

```
    //contentItem.dataBind("screen.Table1Item.Value1", function (newValue) {
    //    contentItem.screen.Property1 =(contentItem.screen.Table1Item.Value1);
    //});
    //contentItem.dataBind("screen.Table1Item.Value2", function (newValue) {
    //    contentItem.screen.Property1 = (contentItem.screen.Table1Item.Value2);
    //});
    //contentItem.dataBind("screen.Table1Item.Property1", function (newValue) {
    //    contentItem.screen.Property1 = (contentItem.screen.Table1Item.Value1) + (contentItem.screen.Table1Item.Value2);
//});
```

Instead of adding the numbers it is appending.Is there anyone who can help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: Have you tried casting them to numeric before trying to add them?

Comment: NO I didn't casted them.I don't know how to cast them in lightswitch 2013

Comment: Maybe they should be the proper data type to start of with.   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/data-types-in-lightswitch/

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
myapp.ViewTable1Item.Property1_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {

    function updateTotalAmount() {
        element.innerText =
            contentItem.screen.Table1Item.value1 +
            contentItem.screen.Table1Item.value2;
    }

    contentItem.dataBind("screen.Table1Item.value1", updateTotalAmount);
    contentItem.dataBind("screen.Table1Item.value2", updateTotalAmount);

};
```

both `value1` and `value2` are set as integers in the table.
`Property1` is a data item set as an integer

[image]